# What probability rule is this? $P(U_1>u,U_2>u) = 1-P(U_1\leq u)-P(U_2\leq u) + P(U_1\leq u,U_2 \leq u)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

What probability rule is this?

> If $U_1$, $U_2$, are  $U(0,1)$ distributed, then
>   $$P(U_1>u,U_2>u) = 1-P(U_1\leq u)-P(U_2\leq u) + P(U_1\leq u,U_2 \leq u)$$

I don't understand the intermediate steps that lead up to this.

Comment: this is the law of inclusion exclusion. If $A,B$ are two sets, then $$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|.$$

Comment: I still dont see what is what

Answer (score 3):

$$\{U_1>u,U_2>u\} = \{U_1>u\}\cap \{U_2>u\}$$
Then the opposite event is 
$$\{U_1>u,U_2>u\}^c = \{U_1\leq u\}\cup \{U_2\leq u\}$$
Probability of the opposite event is 
$$
\mathbb P(\{U_1>u,U_2>u\}^c) = \mathbb P(\{U_1\leq u\}\cup \{U_2\leq u\}) 
$$
$$
= \mathbb P(U_1\leq u) + \mathbb P(U_2\leq u) - \mathbb P(U_1\leq u, U_2\leq u).
$$
since 
$$\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A\cap B).$$
And 
$$
\mathbb P(U_1>u,U_2>u) = 1- \mathbb P(\{U_1>u,U_2>u\}^c).
$$

Comment: Awesome! thanks

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).